# Which format is github id_rsa.pub in?

Tags: git, github

Which format is github id_rsa.pub in ? If not in openssh , how do I convert it to the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses RFC 4716 format:  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt

It is compatible with OpenSSH.  No conversion is necessary.